# What is the more elegant/shorter replacement for wrapper (technical)

Tags: word-request, terminology

So I have something called `node`.

And I have something that wraps it `nodeWrapper`. But it feels so cumbersome.

Is there a better word? I feel there should be some word, like
`archNode`, `superNode`, but I don't like these either. It would be great if someone can suggest the right prefix with latin or greek roots. Thanks!

Comment: Greek, eh? ...epiNode?

Comment: Yes, it feels weird too :) I made some research while waiting for the answers and I think there is no good alternative to wrapper/wrapped... But I still hope.

Comment: What is it that you need that `nodeWrapper` class for, anyway? Understanding its purpose would probably help in finding appropriate names for it (my answer below notwithstanding).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Hey I has wrote the comment just about that under your answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the established domain-specific term is ***wrapper*** (which the OP already knows), and it's inappropriate for ELL to be advising people which "non-standard" term they might use instead.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I tried to not touch the programming aspect of the question, instead I was looking for the appropriate prefix that might be used in english in any technical/science domains, not just programming. Fixed `programming` to `technical` in the title.

Comment: **container** is a generic term that is not domain-specific. It refers to something that holds other things. So we can speak of "container nodes".  Container nodes can themselves be contained by other container nodes.  **wrapper** is a relatively recent term in programming.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo YES. This is the word I have been searching! Albeit longer it's somehow an easier mental model for me. THANK you! Why not posting an answer? I'll select it as the best. And I used to know and use this term, but I have forgot it.

Comment: Please capitalize names of languages in English.What if every noun I wrote in Russian I wrote only in the singular nominative form? Boys, to the boy, of the boy, Oh boy, all the same. Wouldn't that bother you? Thanks.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev  I agree this is a programming question and not an English question.  There are such things as *wrapper* classes that have certain characteristics (which you can research).  If your class has these characteristics, then you should use "wrapper" so that others can understand what it does.  "Container" has a somewhat different meaning, as it implies the class can hold multiple *nodes*.  It may be a good idea to describe how the nodes are *contained* with less ambiguity -- an array, a tree, a linked list, a set, etc.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev  moreover the term "node" itself has a well-defined meaning in programming, as a *vertex* of some kind of *graphical* structure.   If you do call your class a "node" it's probably a good idea to adopt the other conventions of these structures.

Comment: @Andrew programming is about abstractions and mental models. Those mental models which are better represented in the real word are considered as better ones, I think you'd agree on that. For me, maybe personally, `container` is a very familiar concept from the real world and it is even represented in Russian (my language). `Wrapper`, on the other hand may be very familiar for English speakers, I just don't know. If yes, then `wrapper` is the correct answer. For me personally, it is `container`.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev  Programming is also about conventions.  The term "loop" has a specific meaning recognized by all programmers.  If you call something else a "loop" you only introduce unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @Andrew ever heard about Laravel? Well it's a major player in the area of backend programming. And it is famous for breaking old conventions and introducing new terms. It also heavily uses `container` term. DevOPS also uses `container` term. Also blindly following conventions is not always good, I've spent  more than 10 years to realise that.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev  Well, it's up to you what you want to call things.  My suggestion is just a way to avoid having to repeatedly explain your code to new developers.  Novelty is a fine thing, but you shouldn't discount maintainability.  In any case "container" is fine, but it may not imply what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Andrew You are right. If only there was a constant, wide-spread, authoritative source where I can find the evidence that I should use this word and not that one for exactly my case. But there is no such thing. So the only thing I can do is to listen to my intuition + experience + pick the best suggestion from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find that **wrapper node** and **container node** are both widely used.  But which one is "better" to use is really not a question suitable for this site as it is not an "English language" question but a domain-specific question.

That said, I happen to think "container" is a better metaphor than "wrapper".

P.S. If the object contains one or more objects, I'd call it a container. If it provides an interface to a single object only, I'd call it a wrapper.

Comment: The term `container` fits my case perfectly! And it is used widely in Laravel framework and in DevOPS (but I have forgot about this fact).

Comment: wrapping and containing are completely different. Best not to mess with existing programming language.

Comment: @Lambie: It depends on what the outer object does and on the number of inner objects.

Answer (score 4):

"Wrapper" *is* [the established term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class) for what you seem to be describing, so trying to find a different word to describe the same thing is likely counterproductive, and only serves to confuse and to hinder communication.

That said, depending on the details of the situation, your wrapper class *could* perhaps be more specifically described as an "[adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)" or a "[proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)", or one of [various other similar things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350404/how-do-the-proxy-decorator-adapter-and-bridge-patterns-differ) like a "decorator" or a "bridge" or a "facade".  But I would not recommend using any of those terms unless you're *sure* that your class really matches the established definition of one of those design patterns.  And, in any case, none of those words are significantly less cumbersome than "wrapper".

Comment: Great answer! Hey, I see that you are something of SDE as well, can you suggest me the most appropriate option in your opinion for this case: I have an object of some class/interface. I need to associate some data to it, but I don't want to change it's interface (i.e. add properties). So I make another wrapping object for it, where I place the additional data. Is wrapper the best choice?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev: It could be. You _might_ be specifically looking for a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), although it's hard to tell for sure just from that generic description. In any case, I feel like that question is probably better suited for [so], or perhaps even better for [softwareengineering.se].

Comment: Yes, I has been doubting whether it is an appropriate place to ask this question. Regarding decorator, isn't it applied to functions and not to objects/data structures?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev: Not in the sense described e.g. on the Wikipedia page I linked to. You might be confusing it e.g. with [function decorators in Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators).

Comment: JS uses the term `decorator` for functions as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: And node container is less cumbersome? If something is in use by programmers and understood by them, one doesn't change the term. So, this answer is right.

Comment: @Lambie Hi again :) I want to quote myself `Albeit longer it's somehow an easier mental model for me`. Maybe it's kinda subjective, but it's how it is.